# How to can I write a regular expression to match free-text followed by whitespace?

Tags: php, regex

Sorry for the bad title but it's a little complicated to get across in one line.

My data will look something like the following lines (each evaluated separately):

```
JOHNNY BE GOOD        2.55
Rubber Ducky (2012)           123.71
International: INT'L   29.12
```

I'm trying to split them as follows:

```
[JOHNNY BE GOOD][        ][2.55]
[Rubber Ducky (2012)][           ][123.71]
[International: INT'L][   ][29.12]
```

That is, from left-to-right, as much text as possible (including white-space), then any trailing white-space, then a decimal number with 2 decimal places.

So far I have the following expression but my white-space is captured with the text not by itself:

```
/(.*)(\s+)([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: your regex works perfectly on your test data with preg_match(), I just tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `(.*)` is being greedy, i.e., is taking all the characters it can. Try using the laziness operator `?`:

```
/(.*?)(\s+)([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})/
```

or well:

```
/([^\s]*)(\s+)([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})/
```

Comment: No need for the laziness: the (\s+) is will take all the whitespace.

Comment: The `([^\s]*)` option won't work: the entries can have whitespace in their name.

Comment: I'd even forgotten this myself for a minute! Yeah, the text can have white-space but can't end with white-space.

Comment: I went for a combination of the two in the end: `(.*?[^\s])(\s*)([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close, but you're using the `.` character which will match everything including white space. Simply add `[^\s]` from the first captured group to your regex so that it'll look something like this

`(.*[^\s])(\s+)([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})`

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2vo43

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend changing the `(\s+)` part to `(\s{2,})` which makes sure that there's *repeating* whitespace, not just a single character.

You also might want to throw in some line start/end anchors to prevent wildcards from "eating" too much data.  To help balance this out and have them match at newlines, add the `m` flag to your regular expression.

[Example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=im&regex=%5E%28.%2a%29%28%5Cs%7B2,%7D%29%28%5Cd%2b%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%24&input=JOHNNY%20BE%20GOOD%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%202.55%0ARubber%20Ducky%20%282012%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20123.71%0ALAX%20INT%27L%20%20%2029.12)